# unable to get post data in php from data generated by javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

```
<script>
function funcGet(val)
{
  if(val=="Create new category")
  {
     var element = document.createElement("input");
     element.setAttribute("type", "input");
     element.setAttribute("name", "new_cat");
     element.setAttribute("placeholder", "Enter a new category name");
     var foo = document.getElementById("cat");
     foo.appendChild(element);

   }
 }

</script>
<div id="cat">
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter a topic name" name="word"><br/><br/><br/>
<input type="input" name="link" placeholder="Enter a link here"><br/><br/><br/>
<select name ="category" onchange="funcGet(this.value);">
<?php
 displayCat();
 ?>
</select>
<br/><br/>
</div>
<select name="site_type">
<?php
  displaySitetype();
?>
</select><br/><br/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit data">
</form>

<?php
if($_POST['category']=="Create new category") {
  if($_POST['new_cat'])
  {
      $new_cat=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['new_cat']);
      create_new_catentry($new_cat);
      $catname=$new_cat;
  }
  ?>
```

I am not able to get the value of new_cat using $_POST in the same page. What am i doing wrong? I am not able to solve it. I am able to get every other post data from the page without any fault, is there any naming stuff gone wrong? I am not sure what the problem is, is my Javascript wrong?

Update: Please note that the php script down at the bottom is just a small part of a system not the whole part.

Comment: Please reformat your code, currently it looks like you've got PHP code in your HTML (some PHP opening tags are missing).

Comment: @Frits van Campen

Please check now

Comment: You're appending the input element to the parent of the form, not the form itself.

Comment: @KaiQing that's probably it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your javascript add new attribute:

```
 element.setAttribute("id", "new_cat");
```

Comment: Form submits go by `name`, not `id`. The problem is elsewhere.

Comment: can anyone alive explain how this worked? setting an id alone should not have made a difference if the input was not in the form tag UNLESS it was also accompanied by a form attribute that pointed to the id of the form (html5) - in this case it does neither. wtf?

Answer (score 2):

In your JS code you're appending the new `<input>` within the `cat` div, but this way it will be *outside* the `<form>`. Append your field to the form, assigning it an id, like this:

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="catform">
```

JS:

```
var foo = document.getElementById("catform");
foo.appendChild(element);
```

Comment: heh. i didn't post as an answer cause I forget how to target the first element of form in raw js. Update your answer with how to do that or tell the OP to give the form an ID and I'll give you a plus one.

Comment: @KaiQing your comment wasn't posted yet when I started to write my answer, I wasn't trying to "steal" your comment :P
I can't understand what you mean by "targeting" the first element, by the way I was just pointing out the error, I'm not supposed to write code for the application

Comment: I wasnt suggesting that. All I mean is a way to write $('#cat form').append(element) in regular js. I forget how to do that in a non jquery way. but i see you mentioned giving the form an id, so i plussed for that. I don't really care about credit